# Django - How to link tables

Tags: python, mysql, sql, django

Hello to the stackoverflow team,

I have the following two django tables:

```
class StraightredFixture(models.Model):
    fixtureid = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    soccerseason = models.IntegerField(db_column='soccerSeason')  # Field name made lowercase.
    hometeamid = models.IntegerField()
    awayteamid = models.IntegerField()
    fixturedate = models.DateTimeField()
    fixturestatus = models.CharField(max_length=24)
    fixturematchday = models.IntegerField()
    hometeamscore = models.IntegerField()
    awayteamscore = models.IntegerField()

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'straightred_fixture'

class StraightredTeam(models.Model):
    teamid = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    teamname = models.CharField(max_length=36)
    teamcode = models.CharField(max_length=5)
    teamshortname = models.CharField(max_length=24)

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'straightred_team'
```

In the views.py I know I can put the following and it works perfectly:

```
def test(request):
    fixture = StraightredFixture.objects.get(fixtureid=136697)
    return render(request,'straightred/test.html',{'name':fixture.hometeamid})
```

As I mentioned above, this all works well but I am looking to return the teamname of the hometeamid which can be found in the StraightredTeam model.

After some looking around I have been nudged in the direction of "select_related" but I am unclear on how to implement it in my existing tables and also if it is the most efficient way for this type of query.  It feels right.

Please note this code was created using "python manage.py inspectdb".

Any advice at this stage would be greatly appreciated.  Many thanks, Alan.

Comment: I am pretty sure that this code was created using `python manage.py inspectdb`, if so, please state it in your question.

Comment: You sir are a genius.  I have updated the question as requested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [model relationships](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/db/models/#relationships).

Django provides special model fields to manage table relationships.
The one suiting your needs is [ForeignKey](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/fields/#foreignkey).

Instead of declaring:

```
hometeamid = models.IntegerField()
awayteamid = models.IntegerField()
```

which I guess is the result of `python manage.py inspectdb`, you would declare:

```
home_team = models.ForeignKey('<app_name>. StraightredTeam', db_column='hometeamid', related_name='home_fixtures')
away_team = models.ForeignKey('<app_name>. StraightredTeam', db_column='awayteamid', related_name='away_fixtures')
```

By doing this will, you tell the Django ORM to handle the relationship under the hood, which will allow you to do such things as:

```
fixture = StraightredFixture.objects.get(fixtureid=some_fixture_id)
fixture.home_team  # Returns the associated StraightredTeam instance.

team = StraightredTeam.objects.get(team_id=some_team_id)
team.home_fixtures.all()  # Return all at home fixtures for that team.
```

Comment: Appreciate the response.  Not only did you answer the question but you went above and beyond.  Many thanks, Alan.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if this makes sense for `Managed=False`, but I suppose the sane way of doing it in Django would be with

```
home_team = models.ForeignKey('StraightRedFixture', db_column='fixtureid'))
```

And then just using `fixture.home_team` instead of doing queries by hand.

Comment: Sorry, I wish I could accept two answers.  I did try but it does not allow it.  Shame I can't give a percentage to each answer.  The bit that impressed me the most was in aumo answer where he correctly guessed the that it was created by the result of python manage.py inspectdb.  I would upvote you but I can not yet as I am not allowed.  I promise to come back and upvote once I can.